# How to access local ENV variables in angular js

Tags: node.js, angularjs

Is it possible to access ENV variables from angularjs?

I've got an angular 1.2.8 app being compiled via Brunch.io

It's hosted as a basic node app on heroku. (I do compiling locally; then push)

I've read a few things about token replacement during the compile stage for ENV variables.

However I'd much rather be able to push up the code to several different servers and have it resolve the correct local settings using just the ENV variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot get ENV variables on browser. You can send request to a rest service on your server, and get env on backend, then response back to client

Quick example: (Express.js)

```
app.get("/rest/getenv", function(req, res) {
    var env = process.env.ENV_VARIABLE;
    res.json({result: env});
});
```

**Edit:**

You need to protect this rest url with token like strings. Or else, anyone can reach that url and get your environment variable value. This can be security concern

Comment: Thank you I was confused. I needed the ENV variables so I know where to point the front end to the backend.  However I can make the "front end" have a basic rest call.     Thankfully it's nothing that would be a concern security wise.

Comment: Even if you protect the REST url with a token, that doesn't make it secure and never prevent people from getting the environment variable values. Simply because the token is used in AngularJS (Front-end). Therefore anyone can get that token and use it.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple ways of doing it and as mentioned above you could simply make and API call, however that creates an unnecessary delay in your app. 
I would recommend to inject your env variables into your angular constant service on your server. That probably sounds a bit confusing, but it's simpler than it sounds.

I have written a blog post comparing different ways of injecting env varialbes into angular and explaining why you should take this approach: https://medium.com/@kudresov/a-better-way-to-inject-environmental-variables-in-angular-d3b2d01a3c5e

Also I have created sample Node Angular project to show how it works: https://github.com/kudresov/angular-config-vars